# How to set div to fill in remaining place taken by the dynamically sized element

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<div id="body" style="height: 295px; width: 427px; position: absolute; top: 261px; left: 284px;">

   <div id="header">
        Some dynamic text<br/>
        Some dynamic text<br/>
   </div>

    <div id="Content"> 
        <textarea id="text" style="width: 100%"> </textarea>
    
        <input type="file" style="width: 100%">
    </div>

   <div>
</div>
```

I want to set content div to fill remaining space of its parent. The text is generated server side and it causes the height of the header to change.

The output should look like this: file input should be at the bottom of the content with text input filling remaining of the Content. Content itself fills remaining of the Body, which height is influenced by dynamic text.

I am interested only in CSS solution, as this is easy to do with JS. Also, only width and height of the Body div can be hardcoded.

EDIT:
Some clarifications:

1. ## Body is fixed size
2. ## Header is dynamic size, can be of any height. If its height > #Body.height, the rest will be cropped and #Content height will be 0. Alternativelly, if possible, #Header could be limited to max half of the #Body with the rest cropped or scrollable.
3. ## Content doesn't need any special clarification. It contains of fixed file input and dynamicly height textarea

Thx.

Comment: If you want the text to fill the remaining space, shouldn't you be using a textarea?

Comment: Meh, the problem with textarea is that if you set its height with %, in IE it will resize it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand how such a basic thing as control anchoring (or docking) is not something you can do in CSS. The language that is used for presentation not having fundamental thing is just insane...

Anyway, the above thing probably can not be done in CSS as CSS element is not aware of other elements. Or maybe it can, but such solution will certanly include CSS hacks.

I settled with [JQuery LayoutManager framework](http://www.rajeeshcv.com/projects/layoutmanager-jquery-plugin/) for now.

Answer (score 1):

here is a test page showing the html in question:

http://programmingdrunk.com/test.htm

ive taken the liberty to adding colored borders to see what is going on.

**edit:** now the above link has a solution. it looks a bit strange in firefox, ill see if i can fix that

**edit 2:**
final solution as can be seen in the link above is this (let me know if i misread your spec)

```
#text, #Content  {
    height:86%;
}
```

Comment: But if the height of the header is variant then this design expands the 'body' div.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all, what if the header height is > 14% of container?

Comment: Your soultion looks similar, but its not what I want. In your case, div isn't fixed but its expanding as phoenix said. Also, textarea looks fixed too. There is also 86% thingie.

Comment: Also, in IE I am using strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your html makes it really really hard to do what you want. Also, you have not told us what should happen if the content is too high to fit one screen.

Your description makes it sound a bit like you'd want something like:
http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/10/18/the-catfish-part-1/

In order to get good replies, please consider changing of the html structure.

EDIT:
Okay, what you want is just not doable if you want ie to behave. If we drop ie or no-js limitations, then there is a small chance in doing this with table-style layouts. But this is really weird request and you should consider really hard why do you want to do it like this at all.

Comment: Content div has input file which is fixed and text control which should fill the rest of the space.

If Header div contains to much text, Content height should be 0.

Comment: If you can provide the code that can do the same thing using different HTML markup, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float:left` to #header will cause #content to fill remaining space, not sure how to achieve the text area though.

Comment: I tried that before, and it doesn't do it... With height equal to 100% it goes over the container.

Comment: Don't use height: 100% on anything, since #content is a block level element it will fill the space, only the text box won't.

Comment: No, it doesn't fill the div, I tried again !. How can it ? It is shaped based on the controls in it.